# How to 'normalize' data to account for level at baseline?

Tags: repeated-measures, likert

In the beginning of an experiment, subjects are required to report on their initial emotions / mood using Questionnaire#1. After the experiment is conducted, the subjects fill another mood questionnaire#2.

How do we interpret these two sets of data (from the initial questionnaire and the final questionnaire)?

Since it is not possible for every participant to have the same initial emotions or level on the Likert scale (which goes from *strongly disagree* to *strongly agree*) at the start of the experiment, how do we analyze the data to "normalize their emotions" from questionnaires.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What are you trying to get at? **What's your specific research question?** For example, I don't know if the interest is: in questionnaire #2 but accounting for the fact that there were pre-existing differences in emotions at time 1; in change over time in emotions scores; or in having the two sets of scores on a same scale (though it sounds like they both were measured on the same Likert scales).

Comment: Let me clarify. Since there are initial data about baseline emotions and final data, I don't believe that I should ignore the initial data, and consider the final data of how the participants were feeling at the end of the experiment. My question is how do we analyze the data - given that we should account for the initial data that relate to baseline emotions as well. My reasoning is that not all participants are on the same level on the mood scale or have the same emotions at the start of the experiment, that is why they have to indicate their baseline emotions.

Comment: Can you please advise what is the best statistical method I should apply in this scenario to obtain their resultant or net emotions, at the end of the study. This has been referred to as normalizing data by some researchers, which is beyond the scope of my understanding. Thanks –

Comment: 1) Why did you add the `missing-data` tag? 2) I still don't understand your question. In my very first comment, I offered 3 possible research questions, and you didn't pick either of them. What is your **research** question? Why did you measure emotions? What's your experiment? What are you trying to get at?

Comment: At this point, the goal of this study is to evaluate (measure) emotional responses of participants using subjective instrument like self-report questionnaire, in a controlled experiment. This forms part of the bigger picture to answer my main research question on user experience. At this point, I would like to know how the initial data of baseline emotions and the post-experiment data of emotional responses should to be treated. I cannot ignore the baseline emotions, and solely consider the post-experiment data, as I am afraid I won't be reporting the "true emotions" accurately.

Comment: seems to me that the word "normalize" in the title and question is the wrong word and confusing people. You want to analyze the data in a way that takes into account differences among individuals on the first questionnaire. Is it correct to say that your goal is to describe/quantify how much the reported emotions change between the two questionnaires?

Comment: I apologize if I used the wrong term "normalize" however when I read a research article, the author mentioned that he had to normalize the data before proceeding to the analysis of initial (baseline emotions reported) and the post-experiment data.I believe you have a sense of what I imply by now. How do I proceed with those two sets of pre-test and post-test data, as it is clear that initial baseline emotions are not necessarily neutral or similar for all participants. In fact, the post-test emotional responses are affected by the stimuli, and by their baseline emotional state (initial data).

Comment: My pertinent question is whether performing an ANCOVA will help me analyze the above data, as it will take care of the initial (baseline) emotions data. Or is there another statistical method I should use to obtain an accurate "resultant" emotional responses (post-test). If I ignore the baseline data, I am afraid that the just analyzing the post-test data won't be true and accurate, due to the influence of the baseline mood or emotion of the subject, prior to the experiment.

Comment: When you say "experiment", what do you mean? You have 2 groups, treatment vs. control? If so, then yes, ANCOVA with factor=experimental group, covariate=baseline emotion, and dv=post emotion. If all your participants took part in the experiment (i.e. you have an experimental group and no control), then matched-pairs t test.

Comment: Indeed, The same subjects will be taking part in two different experimental conditions: controlled experiment and manipulated experiment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The analysis method you are looking for is called *Mixed Models for Repeated Measures*. See this similar question [Which statistical analyses should I use?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77136/which-statistical-analyses-should-i-use)

Briefly, the data are model as:

$$\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + \mathbf{Z}\mathbf{u} + \varepsilon$$

Where $\beta$ is a vector of fixed effects, and $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector of random effects. The random errors $\varepsilon$ have have covariance matrix $\mathbf{R}$ and the random effects $\mathbf{u}$ have covariance matrix $\mathbf{G}$. The variance of $\mathbf{Y}$ is then $\mathbf{ZGZ' + R}$. A brief overview can be found in its [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model). An introduction to Mixed Models is typically a one semester course at a university.

This model addresses your problem because each subject has their own $\mathbf{R}$ matrix (which can have many different *covariance structures* - such as unstructured, compound symmetry, autoregressive, and more - a structure that is common for all subjects).

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to the right direction. Is mixed model different from ANOVA?

Comment: You might think of it as an extension to ANOVA.

Comment: Is it a Mixed ANOVA of within-subject test that I need to carry out?

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but given the OP's evident level of statistical sophistication is likely to be too advanced.

Comment: So I understand that I should conduct an ANCOVA; need to treat the baseline emotional responses as a covariate. Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Mixed Models for Repeated Measures and include the the baseline emotional responses as a covariate is a right way to solve your question, since it seems that you do not have a control group. only you have two groups, you can treat the baseline emotional response as a covariate to adujst the this potenial confounding factors between groups.

Comment: It seems from the OP's last comment on his question that he does have a control group, and that the design is in fact a repeated-measures one, where all subjects did both the experimental and the control condition.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. and I want to consult you a question that can I adjust some confounding factors using some statistical methods for a uncontrolled prpspective study design.

Comment: I want to consult you a question whether I can adjust some confounding factors using some statistical methods for a uncontrolled prpspective study design. For example, I found the patients with depression had a lower serum BDNF levels after 8 weeks antidepressant treatment, and how can I adjust some confouding factors such as baseline severity, the length of disease to interpret the treatment effect. Thanks!